# how to read a function for all elements in my list in python

Tags: python, compare

I have defined a function to compare two sequences with the def statement. Now I want to read the code of def function for all strings in my list, but I want to compare all strings.

It looks like the following:

```
new_sequ=['XYZ','ZXY'...] example of list


def sequ(s1,s2):

          ..............
          ..............

sequ((new_sequ[0]),(new_sequ[1])) --> i call the function for the 0th and 1st of my list.
```

Therefore I want to read the function for all strings  in my list.

I want to compare 0th with 1st, 0th with 2nd, 0th with 3th, and so on.

After that, I want to compare the 1st with 2nd, 1st with 3rd element, and so on, and then the 2nd with 3th, 2nd with 4th, etc.

Comment: Hi, perhaps use a lambda?

Comment: i am new in python. can u explain what i can reach with lambda ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this what you need,

```
new_seq = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
def sequence_read(new_seq):
    return print(new_seq[i], new_seq[i+1])
try:
    for i in range(len(new_seq)):
        sequence_read(new_seq)
except:
    print('Done!')
```

the output will be:

```
ABC DEF
DEF GHI
Done!
```